# Problema para hacer petición con Postman (Windows 10) a servidor Laravel (Ubuntu en VirtualBox)

Tags: laravel, windows, postman, virtualbox

Tengo un proyecto de Laravel desplegado en Ubuntu 21.04, simulado con VirtualBox, y estoy tratando de hacer peticiones con Postman desde el host, Windows 10, pero no consigo ver que tengo mal configurado, porque las peticiones GET fallan.

En Ubuntu tengo lanzado el servidor:

[image: Servidor lanzado]

La configuración del archivo hosts es la siguiente:

[image: Archivo Hosts Ubuntu]

La configuración de red es:

[image: Configuración de RED]

El caso es que si en la máquina virtual hago una consulta con Postman sí que funciona correctamente:
[image: Petición Postman Ubuntu]

Si hago ping, desde la máquina host a la guest y desde la guest a la host ambos pings acaban bien:
[image: Ping a Windows]

[image: Ping a Ubuntu]

La configuración de VirtualBox es con red NAT:

[image: Detalle RED NAT VirtualBox]

[image: Configuración RED VirtualBox]

Y por último la configuración de del fichero hosts de Windows 10:
[image: Archivo Hosts Windows 1]

También he probado con:

[image: Archivo Hosts Windows 2]

Pero al lanzar la petición con Postman, esta me da error:

[image: Petición Postman Windows]

Con la configuración alternativa, usando la IP: 192.168.99.1 se envía la petición, pero no obtengo respuesta.

¿Alguien sabría decirme porque me falla? ¿Tengo algo mal en la configuración?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras varios días de darle vueltas a posibles soluciones que he ido encontrando finalmente he dado en el clavo, me faltaba crear una regla de reenvío de puertos para redirigir la petición desde la máquina host a la guest:

[image: Redirección de puertos]

Espero que esta solución le sirva a alguien en el futuro, si se topa con mi problema.