# ¿Cómo mostrar pagina web desplegado en Virtual Box en el equipo local?

Tags: apache, virtualbox

Buen día. Estoy tratando de cargar una pagina desplegado en un servidor virtual en mi equipo local sin éxito.
cuando comprobé la conectividad de respuesta tanto en el equipo local como en el virtual si reconoce haciendo ping.
A continuación se muestra una imagen del estado actual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Imagen muestra que carga la pagina del apache en el servidor virtual  pero NO en el equipo local. También se muestra la configuración del servidor virtual.

Comment: Mírate esta solución a ver si te sirve: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/475720/problema-para-hacer-petici%c3%b3n-con-postman-windows-10-a-servidor-laravel-ubuntu?rq=1

Comment: Prueba a indicarle el puerto con el que quieres comunicar en la url del navegador: 192.168.1.148:80

Comment: Muchas gracias . si estaba relacionado. era por el firewall. agregue -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT en /etc/sysconfig/iptables en el servidor virtual y funciono

Comment: @DANIELHS afirmas que lo que te faltaba era agregar esos flags sin embargo aceptas como respuesta "añadir el puerto a la URL", en qué quedamos? Cual de las dos cosas fue la solución?? Ten en cuenta que tú no eres el único usuario en SO, que más gente puede tener esta duda, venir aquí a ver cual ha sido la respuesta.... y todo nuestro esfuerzo ayudándote habrá sido en vano porque no sigues las reglas. Por favor, clarifica cual es la respuesta correcta.

Comment: @DANIELHS Haz lo que pide Benito-B, o bien, dado que has adaptado la solución que te he apuntado, mejor create una respuesta tu mismo y compartela con la comunidad.  En unas 12 horas la podras aceptar y así quedara bien resuelta (dudo que la que has aceptado sea la solución).

Comment: gracias a todos vuestro apoyo. hare las modificaciones sugeridas

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta. en realidad la ip ya tenia el puerto 80 por lo que el error persistía. la solución fue la de abrir el puerto 80 en el servidor virtual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sugerencia de la comunidad aclaro al solución a mi problema. El problema era que  el firewall estaba bloqueando el puerto 80 en el servidor virtual. le di permisos ingresando "-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT"
en la ruta /etc/sysconfig/iptables  así como se muestra en la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego reinicie el firewall y cargo la pagina así como se muestra en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias a todos por su apoyo.

Comment: nota: en mi caso servidor virtual era un SO Linux Centos 6.5